# Fatal Error: Cannot read module file ‘mod_input.mod’ opened at (1), because it was created by a different version of GNU Fortran

Tags: gcc, gfortran, libstdc++

I am getting following error in compiling CaMa-Flood model on Ubuntu 20.04 version.

```
sh compile.sh 
compile.sh: 13: [: =: unexpected operator
*********** mod **********
ar -rv mods.a parkind1.o mod_input.o mod_map.o mod_prog.o mod_diag.o mod_time.o mod_output.o
r - parkind1.o
r - mod_input.o
r - mod_map.o
r - mod_prog.o
r - mod_diag.o
r - mod_time.o
r - mod_output.o
compile.sh: 13: [: =: unexpected operator
*********** lib **********
/usr/bin/gcc -E    -P -I ./ lib_dates.F > lib_dates.f90
/bin/sh: 1: cannot create lib_dates.f90: Permission denied
make: *** [Makefile:16: lib_dates.o] Error 2
compile.sh: 13: [: =: unexpected operator
*********** src **********
/usr/bin/gcc -E    -P -I ./ calc_fldstg.F > calc_fldstg.f90
/usr/bin/gfortran -fopenmp -c -O3 -Wall  -I/usr/local/include -I../mod -I../lib calc_fldstg.f90 -o calc_fldstg.o
calc_fldstg.f90:10:4:

   10 | USE MOD_INPUT  ,ONLY: NLFP
      |    1
Fatal Error: Cannot read module file ‘mod_input.mod’ opened at (1), because it was created by a different version of GNU Fortran
compilation terminated.
make: *** [Makefile:34: calc_fldstg.o] Error 1
compile.sh: 13: [: =: unexpected operator
*********** map **********
/usr/bin/gfortran -fopenmp  generate_inpmat.o   -o generate_inpmat -L/usr/local/lib -lnetcdff
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lnetcdff
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Makefile:21: generate_inpmat] Error 1
compile.sh: 13: [: =: unexpected operator
*********** out **********
/usr/bin/gfortran -fopenmp  vec2map.o   -o vec2map -L/usr/local/lib -lnetcdff
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lnetcdff
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Makefile:27: vec2map] Error 1
/usr/bin/gcc -E    -P -I ./ calc_fldstg.F > calc_fldstg.f90
/usr/bin/gfortran -fopenmp -c -O3 -Wall  -I/usr/local/include -I../mod -I../lib calc_fldstg.f90 -o calc_fldstg.o
calc_fldstg.f90:10:4:

   10 | USE MOD_INPUT  ,ONLY: NLFP
      |    1
Fatal Error: Cannot read module file ‘mod_input.mod’ opened at (1), because it was created by a different version of GNU Fortran
compilation terminated.
make: *** [Makefile:34: calc_fldstg.o] Error 1
```

'GFORTRAN module version '10' created from mod_input.f90'

Based on above and https://users.open-mpi.narkive.com/mOtc0P9T/ompi-fatal-error-cannot-read-module-file-mpi-mod-opened-at-1-because-it-was-created-by-a-different

I understand I feel I need gcc-4.8.3.

I tried installing gcc-4.8.5 using following
[How to Install compiler g++-4.8.5 in ubuntu 20.04](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61945439/how-to-install-compiler-g-4-8-5-in-ubuntu-20-04)

but at

```
make MAKEINFO="makeinfo --force"
```

it gave me following error:
msgfmt: /home/xxxxxx/Downloads/xgcc-4.8.5/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/src/.libs/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.8' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicuuc.so.66)

Can you guide me on how to proceed further?

Thank you.

Comment: You should always try to fix errors from top to bottom because you never know if the following errors have dependencies to the first error. Please start with executing `bash compile.sh` instead of `sh compile.sh`. If this fixes the `unexpected operator` error please update the error log in your question!

Comment: Thank you. bash compile.sh didn't fix the issue.

Comment: `bash compile.sh` didn't fix the first issue with `unexpected operator`? You really get exactly the same output?

Comment: Find out where the offending module comes from and recompile it. Forget the ancient 4.8.